# Set default margin for controls added using Visual Studio's designer

Tags: visual-studio

I would like all controls I drag and drop onto my Windows Forms app to have a default margin of 6 rather than 3. I'm going to be designing lots of GUI's and the snap lines are a great help. Right now it's sort of a pain to have to change the margin for all the controls after they are added, then realign then using the snaplines.

Anyone know if this is possible?